# Exclude the habits from the global todo list

Tags: org-mode

I set habits

```
** TODO Wake Up Early In the Morning
SCHEDULED: <2019-07-17 Wed 05:00 ++1d -0d>
:PROPERTIES:
:STYLE: habit
:LAST_REPEAT: <2019-07-15 Mon 04:30>
```

they display on agenda perfectly

[image]

Unfortunately, it additionally appear in the global todo list upon invoking C-a t

[image]

How could exclude  the habits from the global todo list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override t with  `org-agenda-custom-commands` as

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("t" tags-todo  "-habit")))
```

[The compact Org-mode Guide: Custom agenda views](https://orgmode.org/guide/Custom-agenda-views.html#Custom-agenda-views)

[The Org Manual](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Custom-Agenda-Views)